# x-cart 5.3.1.3 Clean URL and Static pages not working

Tags: apache, url, static, x-cart

I have been baffled for a few days with this one. When using Clean URLs, all .html pages redirect to the homepage. This happens to both static and dynamically generated pages. But, all .php pages work correctly. I'm using the following .htaccess and I am running SSL on the domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This info came from the original install, and several sources online. I'm not an expert by any means and could really use some help. Most of this is foreign to me.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Also, all static pages redirect to the home page even when the Clean URL switch is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
  RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

  RewriteRule (^|/)\. - [F]

  # Admin.php redirect rules.
  # Uncomment underlaying lines and replace <new_admin> with your path to admin.php.
  # Any requests to <new_admin>.php will be redirected to the real admin.php file.
  # RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  # RewriteRule ^admin\.php(.*)$ - [NS,NC,L,R=404]
  # RewriteRule ^<new_admin>\.php(.*)$ admin.php$1 [NC,L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml(\?.+)?$ cart.php?target=sitemap [NC,L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^((([/_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)(/?)(\.([_a-z0-9-]+))?$ cart.php?url=$5&last=$4&rest=$3&ext=$7 [NC,L,QSA]

  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at original .htaccess:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xcart/xcart5/master/src/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((([/_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)(/?)(\.([_a-z0-9-]+))?$ cart.php?url=$5&last=$4&rest=$3&ext=$7 [NC,L,QSA]
```